# Should I declare an array after I read the size of it?

Tags: c++, gcc, variable-length-array

I recently discovered that this kind of declaration works with my C++ compiler

```
int h, w;
cin>>h>>w;

int a[h + 1][w + 1], f[h + 1][w + 1];
```

Should I use this type of declaration to mitigate the space complexity rather than declaring the array before acquiring the actual, requested size?

Answer (score 6):

Those are non-standard extensions supported by some compilers. Don't count on them. It will be better to use `std::vector`.

```
int h, w;
cin >> h >> w;

std::vector<std::vector<int>> a{h + 1, std::vector<int>{w + 1}};
std::vector<std::vector<int>> f{h + 1, std::vector<int>{w + 1}};
```

Answer (score 5):

[Variable-length automatic arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are allowed in [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) but not in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). As an extension GCC accepts them, but if you build the following example with `-std=c++14` and `-pedantic`, you'll get warning:

```
void foo(int n) {
    int bar[n];
}
```

> warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'bar' [-Wvla]

I don't recommend to use it, [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) has its own dynamic array type, called [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

The other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45646711/7893951) shows a great example of construction an `std::vector` with `h + 1` copies of elements with value `std::vector<int>(w + 1)` which is an other `std::vector` with `w + 1` [default-inserted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable) instances of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern C++ won't allow determining size of an array in the run time. As the other answers specified c99 allows it. The best approach is using vectors.

For example try to compile this code in Microsoft Visual Studio and see what happens.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int arr[size]; // 8th line
}
```

Error(s):

```
source_file.cpp(8): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
source_file.cpp(8): note: failure was caused by non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
source_file.cpp(8): note: see usage of 'num'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x64
```

What you should use is vectors. What vector does is, it determines the size at the run time. You can put more elements inside and it'll size get larger. You can remove more elements on the go and then it'll size get smaller.

But be careful, don't mix capacity with size. Here's an example code to let you see how capacity works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "Adding elements!" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(6);
        cout << "Capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
    }

    cout << "Removing elements!" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        v.pop_back();
        cout << "Capacity: " << v.capacity() << endl;
    }
}
```

Linux x64 output:

```
Adding elements!
Capacity: 1
Capacity: 2
Capacity: 4
Capacity: 4
Capacity: 8
Capacity: 8
Capacity: 8
Capacity: 8
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Removing elements!
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
Capacity: 16
```

Even if I remove the elements later, capacity will remain at its last value.

Capacity returns the size of the storage space currently allocated for the vector, expressed in terms of elements.

Size returns the number of elements in the vector.

Have fun, and good luck!

**Edit**: Also capacity changes from OS to OS.

Microsoft x64 output:

```
Adding elements!
Capacity: 1
Capacity: 2
Capacity: 3
Capacity: 4
Capacity: 6
Capacity: 6
Capacity: 9
Capacity: 9
Capacity: 9
Capacity: 13
Removing elements!
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
Capacity: 13
```